# Chrome Devtools: all watches not available

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging, scope, google-chrome-devtools

I get errors working with Swagger-ui, and trying to figure out the cause by using Chrome built-in JavaScript debugger.

I set some watches, but, strangely, `<not available>` is output instead of their values, though they ought to be in the current scope.

Here is a screenshot of Devtools:

[image: Here is a screenshot of Devtools]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Variable in the "Local" scope in the sidebar pane doesn't seem to correlated with the selected source code either. Looks like a bug to me as if debugger highlighted wrong position. Could you create a bug report at crbug.com/new with reproduction steps?

Comment: @YurySemikhatsky I'll try to reproduce, in case of success I'll create it. I actually messed smth with Swagger, but resolved for now, so I have to remember how to mess like that :)

Comment: @YurySemikhatsky "the variable in watch expression must be used in the local scope, otherwise it's `not available` even if it has been declared in closure scope"  I want to know is the proposition right?

Comment: I have the same problem. Any solutions?

Comment: @Jose Perhaps you are debugging code restored from minified version?

Comment: Possible. In that case, no chance, right? Is there any signal in the dev tools to know if that's the case?

Comment: @Jose There is such a signal: text "(source mapped from <filename.js>)" in bottom right corner of source code view.

Comment: I'm having the same Issue in 2023. Thinking this is a bug because removing the live expressions, restarting chrome, and re-applying the live expressions makes them work again